# To Scroll to the top of page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, master-page

I'm using `angularjs` & `sharepoint 2013`. I have implemented the SPA model in one page where the entire page refresh may not happen. Here, the scroll bar is not always going to the top of page since, the page load is not happening. Hence, I have used the `anchorScroll()` in `angularjs` to scroll to a specific ID. This was working fine for id 's4-bodyContainer', but at that time the `suiteBar` is not showing by default. When click on that bar and scroll up, I'm able to get the same. Is there any way to scroll up to the top of the page, so that the `suiteBar` also gets visible by default ?

Comment: try  $("#s4-workspace").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");